# Prevent spark catalyst from optimizing and moving dynamic parallelism

Tags: apache-spark, parallel-processing, apache-spark-sql, catalyst-optimizer

I need to dynamically set `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` during the execution of my spark job.
Initially, it is set when starting the job, but then after various aggregations, I need to decrease it over and over again.

However, catalyst tends to push this backward (into earlier operations) - even though I do not want it to happen.
My current workaround is to use a checkpoint which breaks the lineage of catalyst.
But a checkpoint 1) writes to disk 2) needs to have the previous operation cached, otherwise, it is recomputed.
This means I need to cache and checkpoint i.e. write to disk twice if the data is too large for the memory.

Obviously, this is slow and less than ideal.
Is there another way to tell catalyst to **not** apply the decreased parallelism before the point where I actually want it to happen in the lineage?

Comment: How can checkpoint influence Catalyst? I cannot find such texts and cannot relate to your question.

Comment: not sure if catalyst is behind the partitioning scheme. `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` sets the number of partitions every time aggregations are performed and the data moves over the network. Ideally, this should be a higher number for bigger datasets.

Also, just to confirm, the checkpoint you are referring to is a simple `write` action or the spark sql checkpointing mechanism?

Comment: A checkpoint does two things: 1) it writes to persistent storage for recovery 2) breaks the lineage of catalyst https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/spark-rdd-checkpointing.html

Comment: Currently it is a spark SQL native checkpoint, i.e. `df.checkpoint(true)`. The thing is that I observed that these dynamic spark configuration changes leak backward in the DAG and I could only contain them properly when breaking the lineage with a checkpoint.

Comment: Simply writing a file via. `df.write.parquet` should be slower as additional compression/serialization applies if I understand the internals correctly.

Comment: Some examples of the plans you are facing ? (analyzed, optimized and physical ?)

Comment: This is what I mean: unless I explicitly break it, the parallelism settings seem to move back in time and also affect previous operations. The only workaround I found was to explicitly break the lineage, i.e. via a checkpoint. Unfortunately, I do not have a query plan at hand now that I would be allowed to share.

Comment: OK, interesting observation. But how is it moving backwards?

Comment: Well operations before setting it are affected as well and are slowed down or fail due to less parallelism.

Comment: @GeorgHeiler Can you anonymize anything ? I really would like to help, but without the plans, I strugggle to understand your problems and how it could be fixed :s

Comment: I will try to develop an example, if this fails, I will look into anonymization.

Comment: Thanks a lot @GeorgHeiler ! :) Do not hesitate to ping thebluephantom and me afterwards :)

Comment: What I already recognized: a `checkpoint` does not seem to be the only option. A simple: `df.cache` (assuming one could fit it in memory) also works to separate the change in shuffle parallelism.

Comment: running the code locally on a single node installation I could not reproduce the behavior. I will run it one the cluster again and try to report query plans. However, it will take a while as it is currently completely busy. Most likely in 1 or two days, you should hear back from me.

Comment: I have some more details now.
Two different spark jobs were compared.
Job 1: Indeed for this job having the additonal checkpointing & chacking to prevent leakage seems to be not required / the operation does not leak.

Comment: Job 2: This one is different. I noticed that checkpointing is not mandatory, but rather that executing `df.cache` is enough. Also, note: that a `df.sort("foo").write.parquet("path")` happends after setting the reduced  paralellism. When applying `cache` it runs for about 35 minutes, when omitting cache: 4 hours and when omitting cache and sort again only for 35 minutes. This seems to be really strange: a cache should only help if the dataframe is reused. But it looks like the `sort` retriggers parts of the DAG multiple times.

Comment: So again, no leakage of the dynamic parallelism, even though it looks like (and mislead me in thinking so). However, still I do not understand why a simple `sort` without the cache is so much more complex than without as this would not result in reuse of the same dataframe i.e. warrant caching to speed things up.